# Subclassing ActiveRecord accessors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the recommended way to wrap an ActiveRecord accessor?

Given something like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I would like to be able to make it that, for example, `@post.comments` returns randomly sorted comments.

Of course I could create another method, like `random_comments`, but I would like to know if there's a less error prone way (I don't want to have to remember to call the `random_comments` method).

Calling `super` doesn't work, as the `comments` method is created reflectively on the `Post` class and not inherited.

So how would you do it?

Comment: Be wary as you're not talking about simpy overriding attributes, which is easy via `read_attribute`, but rather associations.  This probably is a bad idea, as you'd be throwing away all the association proxy methods (`comments#create`, `comments#clear`, and so on).  You might consider using a scope or assocation extension for this, resulting in `comments.randomized` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def comments_with_randomness
    comments_without_randomness.shuffle
  end

  alias_method_chain :comments, :randomness
end
```

Now, calling `@post.comments` should return comments in random order. But, remember, it would be an array and not an active relation.

Answer (score 1):

You may define default order like

```
has_many :comments, :order => "RAND()"
```

RAND() will works only if database engine supports so, (Mysql supports)

Comment: thanks, but while useful, your answer only solves the specific case, which was just an example. thanks anyway though

Comment: and what is the real hidden goal? ;)